# What would the port of an airship be called?

Tags: steampunk, terminology

Marine ships and boats have ports. Airplanes have airports. In scifi spaceships can have space ports. What would be the airship equivalent in a steampunk world where marine ships are still heavily used? So that avoiding the use of *port* would keep things non-ambiguous.

Comment: Welcome, if you have a bit of time spare, then check out the [tour] and the [help]. This may well be a part of your fictional world, but it might, in future be best to as for "single word requests" on [english.se] where they are on-topic. I suspect that you already have the best answers that you're going to get here, so voting to close as off topic - not about worldbuilding.

Comment: is there a reason an airship wouldn't dock at an air*port*?

Comment: @Chickensarenotcows Thanks for letting me know. I'm okay with it if a mod wants to migrate this question to English.SE.

Comment: Historically, ports were for ships and airports were for airships (so that would be the best word in my sense). Then, airplanes appeared and used airfields, which became known as "airports". Then, airships disapeared, leaving only airplanes on airports

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I like **aerodrome**.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerodrome

> In the early days of aviation, when there were no paved runways and
>   all landing fields were grass, a typical airfield might permit
>   takeoffs and landings in only a couple of directions, much like
>   today's airports, whereas an aerodrome was distinguished, by virtue of
>   its much greater size, by its ability to handle landings and take offs
>   in any direction. The ability to always take off and land directly
>   into the wind, regardless of the wind's direction, was an important
>   advantage in the earliest days of aviation when an airplane's
>   performance in a crosswind takeoff or landing might be poor or even
>   dangerous. The development of differential braking in aircraft,
>   improved aircraft performance, utilization of paved runways, and the
>   fact that a circular aerodrome required much more space than did the
>   "L" or triangle shaped airfield, eventually made the early aerodromes
>   obsolete.

Airport implies a runway, as noted.  A blimp does not need a runway and early airplanes might need a variety of takeoff directions according to wind.  A large field suitable for hosting all manner of airships could be (and was!) called an aerodrome.

Answer (score 4):

It's called an [Airship Docking Station](https://www.alamy.com/stock-photo/airship-docking-station.html).

The top of the Empire State Building was designed as the mooring mast for an airship docking station for Zepplins, but it was never used.  (The real reason was to make it taller than the Chrysler Building.)

[image: Fake photo.]

Fake photo ([The Empire State Building as Airship Docking Station - The New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2010/09/26/realestate/26scapes.html)).

Answer (score 2):

In his 1908 novel "[The War in the Air](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_War_in_the_Air)" H. G. Wells refers to them as **"aeronautic parks"**.

Comment: I like this. I think I am going to use it in one particular case as it has a ritzy kind of ring to it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out there are many kinds of airships in real life. The most common are airplanes, then helicopters, and there are still a few dirigibles running around (for steampunk, I assume these are the airships you care about). They come to dock and stage from locations that are generally called... drum-roll please... AIRPORTS!!!

Heck the name going around for places for spacecraft to stage from is "spaceport". Maybe not all that exotic - use some of the other excellent answers in this thread for that. However, the actual, factual answer to the question is the mundane airport.

Comment: Potential problems: 1. "airport" seems to have first been used (to refer to something other than a porthole that opens to the exterior air of a ship) in 1919, while "aerodrome" dates back to 1902. 2. an "airport" is a subset of "aerodrome", making it a more specific term where, perhaps, a more general term is wanted.